# How to stop Google's "Google prevented suspicious attempt..."

Tags: gmail, security

I tried login in to my Gmail account from another city...

A week has passed, and every time I do a Google search or use a Google product, I keep getting this message at the top: "Google prevented suspicious attempt..."

I do NOT know what they want me to do.  But I am seriously getting tired of dismissing it.

I realize that I can turn off the alert all together...

But is there a way I can just confirm that the activity was by me, and make it stop alerting me?

Btw, I have already clicked the "review activity" button several times...

Like I said I know how to turn this feature off altogether - that's not what I'm after...

Comment: Have you completed the Security Checkup on [Gmail security tips](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7036019?hl=en)?

Comment: It is there for security reasons.

Comment: Pray tell exactly how do you disable this? It prevents me from logging in at all when I'm in a different city

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you might have some other security alerts into your account that you haven't reviewed yet. 
Here's a simple way to do that:

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup
- You will see this security checkup box:

[image: Google Security Checkup]

- Click on the unresolved issues.

[image: Unresolved Security Issues]

- Click on the 3 dots menu on top right of the specific issue and choose appropriate response.

[image: Resolve the Issues]

- Do this for all of the unresolved issues and you shouldn't see alerts anymore.

I hope it helps!

Comment: That was driving me nuts - thank you for the detailed description!

Comment: possibly of interest: [Google suspicious activity warning persists for 4 days despite my saying I recognize it, does this indicate additional security issue?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/214981/115702) I also see issues but they don't make sense to me, any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure about this @uhoh, this might be just a caching issue. I've never seen this.